# modifying the registry key value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, registry

I have a registry path of the following

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\COMPANY\COMPFOLDER
```

inside `COMPFOLDER`, I have a string value called "Deno" whose value is 0. I wish to change its value to 1 by code whenever I execute the code. Can anyone help me?

Comment: How did the value *get* in that registry key in the first place? I assume that you used the [`Microsoft.Win32.Registry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class to write it, so you should use the same class to *modify* it. What problems did you have when you tried to do this?

Comment: Use the Registry class as described here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx

Comment: I'd assume that he navigated to the registry, copied the path and is desirous of creating a program to make changes to it through code.. Just a guess but that's how I got here. I appreciate your answer Cody Gray. It answered my question in part.

Answer (score 68):

It's been a while I did reg hacks, but something like this could work:

```
RegistryKey myKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Company\\Compfolder", true);
if(myKey != null)    {
   myKey.SetValue("Deno", "1", RegistryValueKind.String);
   myKey.Close();
}
```

Comment: `myKey` should be in a `using` statement. See the [remarks for `RegistryKey`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Comment: Since the key I had to modify started with HKCU, I replaced "Registry.LocalMachine." with "Registry.CurrentUser." and it worked all right. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

```
using (RegistryKey key = regKeyRoot.OpenSubKey(KeyName, true)) // Must dispose key or use "using" keyword
{
    if (key != null)  // Must check for null key
    {
        key.SetValue(attribute, value);
    }
}
```