# Add message to logon screen windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, winlogon

I know that in windows 8, certain applications have a notification on the lock screen, and some fingerprint readers can add messages to the logon screen in windows 7 and older machines.  Is it possible for a program to display a message on the logon screen for Windows 7 using c#?  If so, can that message be dynamic?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to add/changes the logon screen message. It involves updating the `legalnotiecaption` and `legalnoticetext` values in the registry.

See this article for a detailed walkthrough: [Display a Startup Message Box in Windows 8](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/83f858/display-a-startup-message-box-in-windows-8/) 
It will work for Windows 7 also, since we are modifying the registry keys (which haven't changed between windows versions).

[image]

As for whether the message can be dynamic, I am not sure, since it comes from the registry. I guess you could write a C# app that stores the current / existing values for those 2 registry entries, then [updates them at startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8816229/325521). (Don't forget to call `Close()` on the `RegistryKey` object in your C# code :)

Also, if you are "afraid" of modifying the registry entries directly, you can make the same changes by updating 2 options in the Local Security Policy. Behind the scenes, the 2 updates eventually update the same 2 registry keys - `legalnotiecaption` and `legalnoticetext`.

See: [Create a logon message for users in Windows 7 | 8](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-logon-message-for-users-in-windows-7)

- Run secpol.msc and hit Enter to open the Local Security Policy
- Expand Local Policies > Select Security options.
- In the RHS pane, double click `Interactive logon: Message title for users attempting to log on`. Change and save it.
- In the RHS pane, double click `Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on`. Change and save it.

Comment: @N.Soong from the VERY FIRST line in the article explaining it *"In this article we explain how to display a startup message box in Windows 8. This same functionality is available in Windows 7."*

Comment: @N.Soong It should work for both versions. I also updated the post to use Local Security Policy to achieve the same effect. Behind the scenes, this approach also modifies the same 2 registry key values.

Comment: The idea I had was to have a countdown timer on the logon screen.  As this is constantly changing, will this still work?