# How to change desktop/folders Icons size programmatically C#

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, icons, windows-10

I'm developing a WPF that needs to make desktop icons and folder icons bigger while the WPF is active 
and returns them to their previous state when closing the WPF

basically I want to be able to control the following options programmatically:

Folders icons :
[image: folder icons]

desktop icons:

[image: desktop icons]

also how to change folder option to single click mode :
[image: folder options]

Comment: https://www.sevenforums.com/customization/321789-change-desktop-icon-size-via-registry.html

Comment: @apocalypse any advice on how to apply these registry changes in C# code ?

Comment: Use the `Registry` class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816178/modifying-the-registry-key-value

Comment: There's no API for this. The user already has a way to do this.

Comment: Ask yourself, what if two programs did this? What if some other app wanted small icons?

Comment: @Anders The WPF i'm working on does customization to display setting to improve user experience (bigger icons) , but if there is no such api , will have to tell him before using the application .

Answer (score 2):

Folder icon settings are often per-folder and you will have a hard time forcing your preferences on them. You can probably find some descriptions of the registry locations and format if you search the internet for "shellbags" but this puts you in undocumented territory.

The desktop icon mode can probably be changed by undocumented/hacky means but you should just let the user do it.

You might be able to change the double-click mode by playing with [`fDoubleClickInWebView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759785(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`SHGetSetSettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762200(v=vs.85).aspx).