# Can i use C# to automatic tick the Internet Option > Advanced setting > Security > "Use TLS 1.2"

Tags: c#, .net, windows-8, internet-options

Can we write a C# code to automatic tick "Use TLS 1.2"?

This is manual step:-
Go into Internet Options > Advanced then down to the Security section, and tick the box for "Use TLS 1.2".

Is there any way to tick it programmatically in C#.

Comment: Most of those are Reg key. you can simply modify them with win32 or executing them in a command shell.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi , here is the falg you looking for. Now it's a dupe of "How to modify registery key in C#"(e.g: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816178/modifying-the-registry-key-value) of many dupe target) or "How to execute cmd command in c#"(e.g:[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) of many dupe target)

Comment: Btw some of the reg key name may depends on the Windows version or patch. and may differ from the one in the MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

Use UI Automation Test Library from microsoft. It's used for testing purpose but it can work here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/ui-automation-test-library

Answer (score 0):

Most of Internet option are Reg key. 
You can simply modify them with [win32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry) or executing them in a command shell.

The key is specified in this MSDN article [1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi).
 and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn786418(v=ws.11))

Now either ["How to modify registery key in C#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816178/modifying-the-registry-key-value)
 or ["How to execute cmd command in c#"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands).