# Add files to windows context menu C#

Tags: c#, registry

how can I add files to the windows right click context menu. I've searched online and I couldn't really find results for C# its all manual, and I'm trying to make a extractor for .Zip and others(If your asking for the purpose).

Comment: And by "manual", you mean modifications to Windows' registry. You can make registry changes with C#. What do you have an issue with, figuring out what registry changes to make, or doing the modifications with c#?

Comment: modifications with C#

Comment: Does this answer your question? [modifying the registry key value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816178/modifying-the-registry-key-value)